# How to open git project from IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, git, intellij-idea

I have a directory `MYPROJECT`, which contains subdirectory `.git` in it and subdirectory `MYPROJECT` (subdirectory of the same name as parent directory).

This project was ran under Eclipse, but was not under Eclipse workspace parent directory because it was git-controlled.

How to open this project from within IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, IntelliJ has very comfortable git integration. It should be enough to just open the folder via the menu:

```
  File -> Open... -> /path/to/MYPROJECT
```

Or do you want to transfer any settings from the Eclipse project that are not automatically recognized by IntelliJ?